# Optimize docx4j performance

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using docx4j 2.8.1 to replace texts and a logo within the word files. Now I want to improve performance since the processing of about 50 documents is quite slow. What options are recommended to increase performance of docx4j?

The code to replace the strings (not the logo) looks like:

```
 String xml = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true);
 HashMap<String, String> mappings = buildReplaceMap(userData);

 Object obj = XmlUtils.unmarshallFromTemplate(xml, mappings);
 documentPart.setJaxbElement(obj);
```

Comment: I assume you're processing the 50 documents through a single JVM instance (so you're only incurring JAXB Context init delay once)?

Comment: yes. What I observed is that if the documents are generated concurrently, each in its own thread, the procedure takes even longer than if the documents are generated one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Please try http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20130328.jar

It contains an experimental variableReplace method.  Assuming documentPart and mappings as per your question, you can call:

```
documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);
```

You don't need documentPart.setJaxbElement.

In my testing with a 175 page document, processing took 1/3 sec (roughly 3 times faster).

Any further performance improvements will come most easily from providing more resources (more cores, if you want to do it concurrently), and more RAM.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Decided to edit the xmls in the zip file by myself, without xml parsing etc, just plain text replacement. This works because of the limited complexity of the use case. However it might be fragile. But it is really fast.

Comment: The relevant code is in docx4j 3.0, so please use that instead of the then current (but now old) nightly build.