# Is there a way to disable spell/grammar check on Microsoft Word using their JavaScript API?

Tags: ms-word, docx4j, office-js, aspose.words, javascript-api-for-office

If not, is there a way to do that with either [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)?

I've stumbled across the question
[docx Template Docx4j replacing text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035688/docx-template-docx4j-replacing-text-in-java). It describes the actual problem I'm facing, which are template variables (like `${some.variable}`) breaking across text runs due to spell check. However, his solution won't work well for me. The best solution I could achieve would be to disable (and maybe re-enable) spell check automatically under the hood.

Comment: We logged tickets in our issue tracking system as WORDSNET-10403 and WORDSNET-10404 to hide spelling/grammar errors in Word document. Please post your query in [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) forum to get notification when these features are available. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't at this point in time, but you can give feedback on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ to request it to be added in future updates to the APIs.

Thanks,
Philip, Software Engineer on the Office Extensibility Team